# TicTacToe Alpha Beta Pruning

Tags: python, minimax, alpha-beta-pruning

**EDIT 30/03/2021: Question was really poorly-worded, reformulating it**

I implemented an Alpha-Beta Prunning algorithm in Python and I was wondering if it is normal for it not to go for the fastest victory route (sometimes it will go for a victory in 2 moves while it could have won in 1).

```py
import math
from collections import Counter
from copy import copy, deepcopy

""" Board Class Definition """
class Board:
    """ constructor """
    def __init__(self):
        # init data
        self.data = [ "." for i in range(9) ]
    
    
    """ copy constructor equivalent """
    @staticmethod
    def copy(board):
        return deepcopy(board)
    
    
    """ play at given coordinates """
    def play_at(self, position, color):
        # check if you can play
        if self.data[position] == ".":
            # make the move
            self.data[position] = color
            return True
        
        # did not play
        return False
    
    
    """ get coordinates of empty pieces on the board """
    def get_playable_coord(self):
        # define coordinates of empty tiles
        return [ i for i in range(9) if self.data[i] == "." ]
    
    
    """ board is full """
    def is_full(self):
        # define tile counter
        c = Counter( [ self.data[i] for i in range(9) ] )
        return ( c["x"] + c["o"] == 9 )
    
    
    """ get winner of the board """
    def get_winner(self):
        # straight lines to check
        straightLines = [ (0, 1, 2) , (3, 4, 5) , (6, 7, 8) , (0, 3, 6) , (1, 4, 7) , (2, 5, 8) , (0, 4, 8) , (2, 4, 6) ]
        
        # check straight lines - 8 in total
        for i in range(8):
            # get counter of line of tiles
            c = Counter( [ self.data[j] for j in straightLines[i] ] )
            
            # different scenarii
            if c["x"] == 3:
                return "x"
            
            elif c["o"] == 3:
                return "o"
        
        # if board is full, game is a draw
        if self.is_full():
            return "draw"
        
        # return None by default
        return None
    
    
    """ get heuristic value of board - for "x" if 'reverse' == False """
    def get_heuristic_value(self, reverse):
        # init variable
        value = 0
        
        # straight lines to check
        straightLines = [ (0, 1, 2) , (3, 4, 5) , (6, 7, 8) , (0, 3, 6) , (1, 4, 7) , (2, 5, 8) , (0, 4, 8) , (2, 4, 6) ]
        
        # check straight lines - 8 in total
        for i in range(8):
            # get counter of line of tiles
            c = Counter( [ self.data[j] for j in straightLines[i] ] )
            
            # different scenarii
            if c["x"] == 3:
                value += 100
            
            elif c["x"] == 2 and c["."] == 1:
                value += 10
            
            elif c["x"] == 1 and c["."] == 2:
                value += 1
            
            elif c["o"] == 3:
                value -= 100
            
            elif c["o"] == 2 and c["."] == 1:
                value -= 10
            
            elif c["o"] == 1 and c["."] == 2:
                value -= 1
        
        # return heuristic value
        if reverse:
            return -value
        else:
            return value



""" Model Class Definition """
class Model:
    """ constructor """
    def __init__(self, color):
        # define parameters
        self.color = color
        self.other = self.get_opponent(color)
        
        # define board
        self.board = Board()
        
        # define winner
        self.winner = None
        
        # 'x' plays first
        if self.other == "x":
            self.make_ai_move()
    
    
    """ get opponent """
    def get_opponent(self, player):
        if player == "x":
            return "o"
        return "x"
    
    
    """ player makes a move in given position """
    def make_player_move(self, pos):
        if self.winner is None:
            # get result of board method
            res = self.board.play_at(pos, self.color)
            
            # check end of game <?>
            self.winner = self.board.get_winner()
            
            if res and self.winner is None:
                # make AI move
                self.make_ai_move()
    
    
    """ AI makes a move by using alphabeta pruning on all child nodes """
    def make_ai_move(self):
        # init variables
        best, bestValue = None, - math.inf
        
        for i in self.board.get_playable_coord():
            # copy board as child
            copie = Board.copy(self.board)
            copie.play_at(i, self.other)
            
            # use alpha beta && (potentially) register play
            value = self.alphabeta(copie, 10, - math.inf, math.inf, False)
            if value > bestValue:
                best, bestValue = i, value
        
        # play at best coordinates
        self.board.play_at(best, self.other)
        
        # check end of game <?>
        self.winner = self.board.get_winner()
    
    
    """ alpha beta function (minimax optimization) """
    def alphabeta(self, node, depth, alpha, beta, maximizingPlayer):
        # ending condition
        if depth == 0 or node.get_winner() is not None:
            return node.get_heuristic_value(self.other == "o")
        
        # recursive part initialization
        if maximizingPlayer:
            value = - math.inf
            for pos in node.get_playable_coord():
                # copy board as child
                child = Board.copy(node)
                child.play_at(pos, self.other)
                value = max(value, self.alphabeta(child, depth-1, alpha, beta, False))
                
                # update alpha
                alpha = max(alpha, value)
                if alpha >= beta:
                    break
            return value
        
        else:
            value = math.inf
            for pos in node.get_playable_coord():
                # copy board as child
                child = Board.copy(node)
                child.play_at(pos, self.color)
                value = min(value, self.alphabeta(child, depth-1, alpha, beta, True))
                
                # update beta
                beta = min(beta, value)
                if beta <= alpha:
                    break
            return value
```

**My conclusion on the question:**

Alpha-Beta Pruning is a depth-first search algorithm, not a breadth-first search algorithm, so I think it is natural for it to pick the first route it finds no matter its depth, and not search for the quickest one...

Comment: Shouldn't the inital alpha/beta call be True for maximizing_player?

Comment: Yes it should if you go from the current board state, but what I did was computing the score for each possible AI move, then picking the best among those

Comment: Did you try and print the outputted score? Do you ever get the winning or drawing score?

Comment: I added some score examples in the post

Comment: On an empty board you should get a score of 0 (equal) since it is always on equal game if both players play correctly.

Comment: Sorry, I See what you do in the heuristic function now. There is no need to count 1 or 2 in a row, you only need to count a win, draw, or loss since you always get to the end of the game in this tiny tree

Comment: Ok, I'm going to change that, and check the results

Comment: apparently my function is really bugged: after changing the heuristic function, I got a score of 1 on an empty board (score of 1 for each child node)

Comment: Please also note that since the game is always drawn your function will return some random move (probably the first one you look at) since no other move will result in a better score. But as humans we know that placing it in the middle is probably the best, so I usually hard-code that move if it is the first move, and then do normal alpha-beta after that. Sort of like an opening book in chess :)

Comment: I took a look and ran the code, and there was nothing wrong with your AB pruning algo or the moves decided, other than the empty board move which has been explained. The AI is choosing the correct moves as far as I can see

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not the answer to the question, but I would like to suggest perhaps simplier approach for AI tac-tac-toe player, which involves calculating whether the position is winning or losing. This will require considering all valid positions that may happen at any time in the game, but since the field is 3x3, number of valid positions is less than 3^9 = **19683** (every position is either 'x', 'o' or ' '). This is not a hard bound, since lots of positions are invalid from the game rules perspective. I suggest you start from here, because the algorithm you are talking about are mainly used in harder games where full search is infeasible.

Hence, all you need to do is to calculate winning/losing metric for every position once after you start the program and then make a decision in O(1). This is acceptable for 3x3 field, but perhaps not much more.

The general approach is described here: https://cp-algorithms.com/game_theory/games_on_graphs.html. In a nutshell you build a tree of possible moves, mark the leaves as winning or losing and work your way up by considering all children transitions (for example, if every transition lead to a winning position for the opposite player, the position in losing).

In case you understand russian, here is a link to the original page: http://e-maxx.ru/algo/games_on_graphs

P.S. I was also playing with this game at some point in the past and implementing this approach. Here is my repo in case you want to investigate: https://github.com/yuuurchyk/cpp_tic_tac_toe. Fair warning: it's written in C++ and the code is a bit ugly

Comment: "you build a tree of possible moves, mark the leaves as winning or losing and work your way up by considering all children transitions (for example, if every transition lead to a winning position for the opposite player, the position in losing)"

Maybe I was wrong from the start but isn't that the principle of minimax (and by extension alpha-beta pruning)?

Comment: Thanks for the links anyways, I'm going to check that and see if I can adapt to them

Comment: @Tartempion I guess it's a bit different, since the graph approach does not introduce any heuristic score for the node. As for the pruning, I'm not familiar with the method, but it seems to me that it does not explore the whole sample space. So I guess it should be run more than 1 time (I might be wrong here). For the game as simple as tic-tac-toe, it might be acceptable to traverse the whole tree once and for all. You can even try shipping a precalculated game tree and get a fully-trained agent from the start (of course, this should be profiled).